# How to find Distance Between two Places using MapPoint using C# using Windows Application?

Tags: winforms, distance, mappoint

I am finding distance between two places using the following code but it is slow takes around 1 minute.

```
MapPoint.Application objApp = new MapPoint.Application();
        MapPoint.Map objMap = null;
        objMap = objApp.ActiveMap;
        Object obj1 = 1;
        objMap.ActiveRoute.Waypoints.Add(objMap.FindResults(txtfrom.Text)
           .get_Item(ref obj1), "");
        objMap.ActiveRoute.Waypoints.Add(objMap.FindResults(txtTo.Text)
           .get_Item(ref obj1), "");
        objMap.ActiveRoute.Calculate();
        txtMiles.Text = objMap.ActiveRoute.Distance.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi use this following code

Instead of .active route calculation

[image]

use c as like this way otherwise :var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));

Comment: c=arcos(a+b) what is "r" here